# ShadCN UI CVA add "color" variant on button trigger error on typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface

I'm still try understand how this CVA works when adding a variant to a components. for example I create this code (based on ShadCN) and I add `color` variant on a button

```
import { cva, type VariantProps } from 'class-variance-authority';
import * as React from 'react';

export const buttonVariants = cva(
  `inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md text-sm font-medium ring-offset-white 
  transition-colors focus-visible:outline-none  disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-gray-200 disabled:text-gray-400 
  `,
  {
    variants: {
      color: {
        default: 'bg-primary text-white hover:bg-primary-dark',
        destructive:
          'bg-danger text-white hover:bg-danger-dark dark:bg-slate-50 dark:text-slate-900 dark:hover:bg-slate-50/90',
      },
      variant: {
        default: 'text-sm',
        outlined: 'border bg-transparent border-slate-200',
        subtle: 'bg-white',
      },
      size: {
        default: 'h-10 rounded-sm p-md',
        sm: 'h-9 rounded-sm p-sm text-xs',
        xs: 'h-7 rounded-sm p-xs text-xs',
        lg: 'h-11 rounded-sm p-lg',
        icon: 'h-10 w-10',
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: 'default',
      colors: 'default',
      size: 'default',
    },
  },
);

export interface ButtonProps
  extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    VariantProps<typeof buttonVariants> {
  asChild?: boolean;
}
```

the question is:

1. why it trigger error `Named property 'color' of types 'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>' and 'VariantProps<(props?: (ConfigVariants<{ color: { default: string; destructive: string; }; variant: { default: string; outlined: string; subtle: string; }; size: { default: string; sm: string; xs: string; lg: string; icon: string; }; }> & ClassProp) | undefined) => string>' are not identical.` ?
2. But if I change the `color` variant to `colors` it won't trigger any error. is there anything I miss or should check?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because the `HTMLAttributes` interface already includes a property named `color`. In this context, `ButtonProps` extends from two distinct interfaces:

- The first is `ButtonHTMLAttributes`, which itself extends from `HTMLAttributes` and includes a `color` property.
- The second is the type generated from `buttonVariants` when using `VariantProps<typeof buttonVariants>`. This process involves taking the information from `buttonVariants` to generate the type, which also results in a `color` property.

The error occurs because there are two properties with the same name `color` that are not identical, leading to a conflict. However, by using `colors` in `buttonVariants`, this conflict is avoided, and everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a late response, but if you want to use the variable `color` it is possible, but requires that you omit it from the attributes you extend

```
export interface ButtonProps
  extends Omit<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, 'color'>,
    VariantProps<typeof buttonVariants> {
  asChild?: boolean;
}
```

and then make sure to pass the color on to cva instead of the underlying element

```
const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  ({className, variant, size, color, asChild = false, ...props}, ref) => {
    const Comp = asChild ? Slot : 'button';
    return <Comp className={buttonVariants({variant, size, color, className})} ref={ref} {...props} />;
  }
);

Button.displayName = 'Button';
```